# .htaccess Rewrite URL different pages with query string

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an old page that used to display multiple products depending on the query string. I want to rewrite the urls with query strings to static pages that are different than the one the old url will be rewritten to.

```
   RewriteRule ^old.php$ new.php

   RewriteRule old.php?product=10 different.php [R=301,L]
```

In this case the old.php gets rewritten to new.php. But old.php?product=1O gets rewritten to **new.php?product=10** instead of different.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot match QUERY_STRING in rewrite rule. You need to use `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}` for matching query string.

Use your rules as:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^old\.php$ new.php [L,R]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^product=10$
RewriteRule ^old\.php different.php [L,R]
```